# Uploading Parquet File Stream with Azure Functions

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-functions, parquet

I'm having a similar problem to the person in this question: [Creating a file as a stream and uploading to Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65041373/creating-a-file-as-a-stream-and-uploading-to-azure)

The problem is that the answer is now outdated, any tips on how to use the latest SDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest **Azure.Storage.Blobs** SDK has a [UploadBlobAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.blobcontainerclient.uploadblobasync?view=azure-dotnet&WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5003203) method which should be the method you are looking for.