# How to create schema for parquet.net using the .net data table

Tags: c#, datatable, azure-blob-storage, parquet.net

I have one data table which I want to convert to parquet file and upload to blob storage.
But i don't have the static schema so how can i do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Use [Cinchoo ETL](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ChoETL.parquet) - an open source library to upload the datatable to azure storage

Here is working sample

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
using (var w = new ChoParquetWriter("Parquet file stream / path"))
{
    w.Write(dt);
}
```

For more information, refer this link below

[Creating a file as a stream and uploading to Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65041373/creating-a-file-as-a-stream-and-uploading-to-azure)